# Slow elasticsearch indexing with mongodb and monstache

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, monstache

I'm trying to integrate elasticsearch to my mongodb with monstache. Monstache, elasticsearch and kibana are working on my local machine. Mongodb is remote. All things seems running but indexing is so slow, hardly indexing single document in 2 minutes.

I have increased refresh_interval of index, heap size of elasticsearch to 4gb and memory buffer to 30%. Server runs on 16gb ddr4.

Here is how I run monstache:

```
monstache -elasticsearch-url "http://localhost:9200" -mongo-url 'XXXX' monstache -direct-read-namespace portaldb.candidate -verbose -resume false -replay false -stats
```

There are millions of documents in db and we need to make faster fulltext searches.